# How to use the language option in synsets (nltk) if you load a wordnet manually?

Tags: python, path, nlp, nltk, wordnet

For specific purposes I have to use the Wordnet 1.6 instead of the current version implemented in the nltk package. I then downloaded the old version [here](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/old-versions/) and tried to run a simple extract of code using the french option.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import nltk
#nltk.download() 
import os
import sys
from nltk.corpus import WordNetCorpusReader

cwd = os.getcwd()
nltk.data.path.append(cwd)
wordnet16_dir="wordnet-1.6/"
wn16_path = "{0}/dict".format(wordnet16_dir)
wn = WordNetCorpusReader(os.path.abspath("{0}/{1}".format(cwd, wn16_path)), nltk.data.find(wn16_path))

senses=wn.synsets('gouvernement',lang=u'fre')
```

It seems that the wordnet I manually downloaded cannot be linked to the files of the nltk module dealing with foreign languages, the error I get is the following :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Stephanie/Test/temp.py", line 16, in <module>
senses=wn.synsets('gouvernement',lang=u'fre')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\wordnet.py", line 1419, in synsets
self._load_lang_data(lang)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\wordnet.py", line 1064, in _load_lang_data
if lang not in self.langs():
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\wordnet.py", line 1088, in langs
fileids = self._omw_reader.fileids()
AttributeError: 'FileSystemPathPointer' object has no attribute 'fileids'
```

Using an english word doesn't generate any error (so it's not that I did not load the dictionary well) :

```
senses=wn.synsets('government')
print senses

[Synset('government.n.01'), Synset('government.n.02'), Synset('government.n.03'), Synset('politics.n.02')]
```

If I use the current version of Wordnet loaded with the nltk module I don't have any problem using french (so it's not a syntax problem with the optional argument)

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
senses=wn.synsets('gouvernement',lang=u'fre')
print senses
[Synset('government.n.02'), Synset('opinion.n.05'), Synset('government.n.03'), Synset('rule.n.01'), Synset('politics.n.02'), Synset('government.n.01'), Synset('regulation.n.03'), Synset('reign.n.03')]
```

But, as precised, I really have to use the old version. I guess this might be a path problem. I've been trying to read the code of the WordNetCorpusReader function but I am quite new with python I don't really see what the problem is so far, except that it doesn't find a special file.

The needed file seems to be wn-data-fre.tab which is located in \nltk_data\corpora\omw\fre. I am pretty sure that I have to change the file with a version compatible with wordnet 1.6 but still, why the function WordNetCorpusReader can't find it ?

Comment: The error is in the `if lang not in self.langs():` block. Maybe there is no 'fre' language in WordNet 1.6? Or maybe it was 'fr'? You should look at the data files...

Comment: @clemtoy, it doesn't work with fr either, I find it hard to conceive that there is no french language in wordnet 1.6 whereas wn domain is built on it and has domains in french. My problem is my bad understanding of the architecture of the files, are the language attached to wordnet version or a different file, there are no .tab in the wordnet 1.6 directory but this doesn't mean that they should be there ?

Comment: @clemtoy, to be more precise, the file the code is looking for seems to be wn-data-fre.tab which is located in \nltk_data\corpora\omw\fre and not in \nltk_data\wordnet where the current version of wordnet is. So I thought that maybe the file wasn't dependent of the version but maybe I'm wrong (I am pretty sure I have to change the file with a version compatible with wordnet 1.6 but the remaining question is where to put it ?)

Answer (score 6):

**Short Answer**:

There is no WordNet 1.6 with the language parameter. There's no way to use `lang='fre'` when loading a different WordNet through NLTK.

---

**Long Answer**:

The `lang=...` parameter is an addition made using the Open Multilingual WordNet (OMW: http://compling.hss.ntu.edu.sg/omw/) that links wordnet of different languages to the Princeton WordNet version 3.0. See https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py#L1050.

The `lang=...` parameter calls the function:

```
def langs(self):
    ''' return a list of languages supported by Multilingual Wordnet '''
    import os
    langs = []
    fileids = self._omw_reader.fileids()
    for fileid in fileids:
        file_name, file_extension = os.path.splitext(fileid)
        if file_extension == '.tab':
            langs.append(file_name.split('-')[-1])

    return langs
```

That looks for the file, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py#L1070:

```
 f = self._omw_reader.open('{0:}/wn-data-{0:}.tab'.format(lang))
```

So `if lang == 'fre'`, then `self._omw_reader = wn-data-fre.tab`.

And the main reason why the omw can't find the `wn-data-fre.tab` in `nltk_data/corpora/omw/` because you've set the `omw_reader` to `wn16_path` when initializing the `WordNetCorpusReader` object, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py#L1006.

Then when loading the french data, it can't find `self._omw_reader.open('{0:}/wn-data-{0:}.tab'.format(lang))`. (see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py#L1419 and https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/reader/wordnet.py#L1070)

---

What you can try to do is this load 2 instances of WordNet:

```
import os
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
from nltk.corpus import WordNetCorpusReader

cwd = os.getcwd()
nltk.data.path.append(cwd)
wordnet16_dir="wordnet-1.6/"

wn16_path = "{0}/dict".format(wordnet16_dir)
wn16 = WordNetCorpusReader(os.path.abspath("{0}/{1}".format(cwd, wn16_path)), nltk.data.find(wn16_path))

def synset2offset(ss):
    return str(ss.offset()).zfill(8) + '-' + ss.pos()


wn16_ids = [synset2offset(ss) for ss in wn16.all_synsets()]
wn30_ids = [synset2offset(ss) for ss in wn.all_synsets()]


senses30 = wn.synsets('gouvernement',lang=u'fre')
senses16 = [ss for ss in wn.synsets('gouvernement',lang=u'fre') if synset2offset(ss) in wn16_ids]
```

Comment: Thank you for your long answer. I suspected a problem of path. That might be solved though, since the file you mentioned, wn-data-fre.tab, can be converted to be compatible with wordnet1.6. The question of the path is too subtle for my level though, so I took your code and replaced the last line by : `senses16 = [convert30to16(ss) for ss in wn.synsets('gouvernement',lang=u'fre')]` where I defined the function convert30to16 using the mapping files available [here](http://www.talp.upc.edu/index.php/technology/tools/45-textual-processing-tools/98-wordnet-mappings/). Thanks again !